# What is wrong with my 2D rotation matrix?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 2d, linear-algebra

I have this rotation matrix for rotating around Z:

```
function rotation4x4(angle: number, output: number[], origin_x: number = 0.0, origin_y: number = 0.0)
{
    let x = origin_x;
    let y = origin_y;

    let r00 = cos(angle);
    let r01 = -sin(angle);
    let r10 = sin(angle);
    let r11 = cos(angle);

    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 0, r00);
    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 1, r01);
    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 2, x-r00*x-r01*y);
    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 3, y-r10*x-r11*y);

    mat4x4_set(output, 1, 0, r10);
    mat4x4_set(output, 1, 1, r11);
    mat4x4_set(output, 1, 2, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 1, 3, 0);

    mat4x4_set(output, 2, 0, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 2, 1, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 2, 2, 1);
    mat4x4_set(output, 2, 3, 0);

    mat4x4_set(output, 3, 0, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 3, 1, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 3, 2, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 3, 3, 1);
}
```

I then multiply all vertices I render with this matrix:

```
x = mat4x4_get(m, 0, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 0, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 0, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 0, 3) * w;
y = mat4x4_get(m, 1, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 1, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 1, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 1, 3) * w;
z = mat4x4_get(m, 2, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 2, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 2, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 2, 3) * w;
w = mat4x4_get(m, 3, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 3, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 3, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 3, 3) * w;
```

But when I try to render a circle of rects rotated around a point I get this:
[image]

The point I want as the center of the circle is in the middle of this shape.

Expected result (But smoother):
[image]

Here I've given each quadrant a color: [image]

Seems like it's only y that isn't correct?

Comment: Although "render a circle of rects rotated around a point" is very descriptive it might help if you added expected result at least.

Comment: Not sure what your origins should be and how these are supposed to work but I see no logic in code using it. Assuming they are zero can you try `mat4x4_set(output, 0, 0, r00);
    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 1, -r01);
    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 2, 0);
    mat4x4_set(output, 0, 3, 0);

    mat4x4_set(output, 1, 0, -r10);
    mat4x4_set(output, 1, 1, r11);` and see if you get a result that makes sense.

Comment: I have both origin_x and origin_y set to zero. When I set them to something else, the whole shape scales when I resize the window for some reason. And yes, I've tried removing them and just put zeroes as you said - same result.

Comment: The origin is supposed to be the point you rotate around. In the test above I have them set to zero and translate everything afterwards instead.

Comment: But have you tried with all the fixes/changes I made in the previous comment? There is more then just a few zeroes.

Comment: `mat4x4_set(output, 0, 0, r00); mat4x4_set(output, 0, 1, -r01); mat4x4_set(output, 0, 2, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 0, 3, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 1, 0, -r10); mat4x4_set(output, 1, 1, r11); mat4x4_set(output, 1, 2, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 1, 3, 0);  mat4x4_set(output, 2, 0, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 2, 1, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 2, 2, 1); mat4x4_set(output, 2, 3, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 3, 0, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 3, 1, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 3, 2, 0); mat4x4_set(output, 3, 3, 1);` gives the same result.

Comment: Maybe a radiant vs. degree Problem?

Comment: I tried converting the angle to radians, but then I just get a little thing that is like 5 degrees long. Also, as long as it's the same number you give to all the cos/sin functions, it shouldn't matter. That number just represents where on the circle you are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry guys. I'm stupid. Look at this code:

```
x = mat4x4_get(m, 0, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 0, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 0, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 0, 3) * w;
y = mat4x4_get(m, 1, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 1, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 1, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 1, 3) * w;
z = mat4x4_get(m, 2, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 2, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 2, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 2, 3) * w;
w = mat4x4_get(m, 3, 0) * x + mat4x4_get(m, 3, 1) * y + mat4x4_get(m, 3, 2) * z + mat4x4_get(m, 3, 3) * w;
```

I use the new x to calculate the y coordinate. Now it works:

[image]

Comment: Haha, *hit happens